# Does removing an interface break code calling methods on the object?

Tags: java, refactoring, binary-compatibility

I need to do some refactoring in Java, and I need to maintain some degree of binary compatibility. In this case I want to remove some legacy interfaces, that are not used anywhere anymore and which require a rather big (and also deprecated) external dependency.

I have class `C` that implements interface `I`, and I have code that calls a method (declared in the interface) on an instance of `C`. The calling code knows that it is using `C`, not just the interface.

```
 class C implements I {
      void theMethod(){} ; // is declared in the interface I
 }

 C object;
 object.theMethod();
```

When I remove the interface from the class definition (but keep all the methods), will the calling code (which does not refer to the interface at all) still work (without a recompile)?

Comment: it takes less time to try than to write and format this question ;)

Comment: done, see the link in my answer for the situations that might interest you if any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will work - as long as it doesn't explicitly refer to interface `I` anywhere.

From [JLS:  Resolution of Symbolic References](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.3.3):

> The binary representation of a class
>   or interface references other classes
>   and interfaces and their fields,
>   methods, and constructors
>   symbolically, using the binary names
>   (§13.1) of the other classes and
>   interfaces

Class `ClientClass` referring to field / method of class `C` contains no implicit references to interface `I` that class may implement.

Comment: Does this mean that I can even remove abstract base classes and put the methods in the now parent-less child class?

Comment: Yes, same rules apply. Base class doesn't even have to be abstract - as long as you "flatten" the entire hierarchy to child class **AND** base class(es) were never explicitly referenced from client code you'll be fine.

Comment: Here's a JLS section on method / constructor declarations: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#45197

Answer (score 2):

It works as long as an object of class `C` is never referred to as `I`.

You can also refer to [Evolving Java-based APIs part 2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Evolving%5FJava-based%5FAPIs%5F2#Evolving_non-API_packages).

Answer (score 1):

You might have a problem with the calling Code if it imports the Interface anywhere. If there is no `import` of the interface in any of the calling code, you can be reasonably confident that your refactoring will work as planned.

Comment: Yes, the only place where the interface in question is used is (or should be by now...) the class declaration.